# ImageMagick creating only one variable

Tags: php, html, imagemagick

Below imagemagick code which works fine by creating "RUb" with the background color "black white black"   and fonts colors will be in "whiteblack white" colors ..

```
 exec("convert -size 30x30 xc:white -font verdana.ttf -fill black -pointsize 30 -gravity     center -draw \" text 0,0 'R' \" R.gif");
exec("convert -size 30x30 xc:black -font verdana.ttf -fill white -pointsize 30 -gravity  center -draw \" text 0,0 'u' \" u.gif");
exec("convert -size 30x30 xc:white -font verdana.ttf -fill black -pointsize 30 -gravity center -draw \" text 0,0 'b' \" b.gif");
exec("convert -background white -bordercolor black -border 1 -gravity center R.gif u.gif  b.gif +append text_bw.jpg");
```

But now i need to use variables for "fonts color" , "label" and "background color" ..how to do that????ex: if i want to create "rub" i need only one variable "$label" not "$label1 , $label2 $label3" ... is there a way to do?? if yes can any please help me with sample code/ example with refrence to the above code..

Comment: What exactly is your question - how to insert a variable into a string?

Comment: yes i need to use variables for "text/label" some what like this $label="rub"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? (bit messy but it's a start)

```
$label = 'rub';
$images = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($label); $i++) {
    $letter = $label[$i];
    $image = $letter . '.gif';
    exec("convert -size 30x30 xc:black -font verdana.ttf -fill white -pointsize 30 -gravity  center -draw \" text 0,0 '{$letter}' \" {$image}");
    $images[] = $image;
}
$images = implode(' ', $images);
exec("convert -background white -bordercolor black -border 1 -gravity center {$images} +append text_bw.jpg");
```